# Mod_rewrite rule not passing PHP variables

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the URL (using mod_rewrite) as requested by the user:

```
http://example.com/question/1/
```

To load this URL from the server:

```
http://www.example.com/question.php?qid=1
```

I am currently using the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^question/([^/\.]+)/?$ question.php?qid=$1 [L]
```

But this does not work. I have tried other things in the .htaccess (such as redirects) and this work, so I know that the .htaccess is being processed.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `qid=` first, and then `page=`? Is this an abstract example? Did you check `print_r($_SERVER);` yet?

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote it. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your example, your rewrite rule should be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^question/(\d+)/?$ /question.php?qid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working still. Running `print_r($_SERVER);` suggests that /question.php/1/ is being loaded...?

Comment: Hmm... Still no luck, and `[PHP_SELF] => /question.php/1/` is in output. Any ideas?

Comment: @samiles I had a similar problem once on an old redhat server and in the end just changed my php file name to (in your case...): `_question.php` and the rule to `RewriteRule ^question/(\d+)/?$ /_question.php?qid=$1 [L]`. That solved my problem concerning mod_rewrite to think that `name` and `name.php` were the same thing.

Comment: @jereon Tried that, no luck.

Comment: @samiles What else do you have in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @samiles I fail to see why that would not work, I normally add `RewriteBase /` after `RewriteEngine On` so you could try that.